# FadeOut and hide Crashing Chrome

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

Trying to get fade/hide working in chrome, When running this code in chrome it freezes the browser, yet it works in IE10 and Firefox, basically is a simple div rolling off the screen and fading out, any help would be appreciated. Also, the div snaps back to its original position after the animation, hence why I was fading out (also it looks cleaner).

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery('.dildobox').click(function () {

var v = document.getElementsByTagName("audio")[0];
v.play();

jQuery("div.dildobox").html('<img src="images/dildo/standstillhop.gif" alt="" />');
jQuery(this).animate({
    left: '-700px',
}, 3000);

jQuery("div#dildodialog").fadeIn(1500).dialog({
    buttons: {
        "Yeah, Baby!": function () {
            jQuery("div#dildodialog").dialog("close");
        }
    }
}).prev().find(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();

jQuery("div.dildobox").fadeOut(500);


});
```

css is as follows:

```
#dildocache{height:1px;width:1px;display:inline-block;}
#dildocontainer {height: 10px;margin: 0;padding: 0;position: relative;width: 10px;}
.dildo{display:inline-block;height: 50px;width: 50px;position:absolute;}
.dildobox {
font-size: 50px;
height: 71px;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
width: 34px;
}
#dildodialog{font-weight: bold;text-align:center;background: url("../images/dildobg.png") repeat scroll 50% top #f8f8f8;color:#000;}
.ui-dialog-buttonset .ui-button-text-only, .ui-widget-header{background: none repeat-x scroll 50% 50% #ad0401!important; color:#fff;}
.ui-dialog-buttonpane{background: none repeat scroll 50% 50% #ad0401!important;}

/* Dildo Page Specific Placements */
.moduletablewelcomedildo #dildocontainer{left: 275px;top: -30px;}
```

and the HTML:

```
<div id="dildocache">
<img src="images/dildo/standstillhop.gif" alt="standstillhop" width="1" height="1" style="visibility:hidden;"/></div>
<div id="dildodialog" title="Where's Dildo?" style="display:none;">
<p>Congratulations! You've found one but there's more to find!<br/>Keep poking around!</p>
</div>
<div id="dildocontainer">
<div id="dildobox2" class="dildobox"><img src="images/dildo/smalldildo.png" alt="" /></div>
</div>
<audio src="http://www.accentuateit.com.au/addon_domains/allowe/images/dildo/yeahbaby.ogg"></audio>
```

Comment: You, um, sure seem to like your dildos.

Comment: Didn't crash [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BlackSRC/Eb3Q8/)

Comment: Haha I was waiting for a Dildo joke ;) haha.

Comment: Ok I managed to fix it by removing the offending HIDE and FADEOUT variations and simply using opacity: 0, as an option for the animation :)
If you want to see the result: http://jsfiddle.net/Eb3Q8/7/
Not sure why it was crashing on my site and not on JSFiddle, but ah well all fixed either way :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I managed to fix it by removing the offending HIDE and FADEOUT variations and simply using opacity: 0, as an option for the animation, which also lets me fade out over course of the animated movement which is fine :) If you want to see the result: jsfiddle.net/Eb3Q8/7 Not sure why it was crashing on my site and not on JSFiddle, but ah well all fixed either way :)